# Dynamic drop down (Country/state) with spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my Spring Application i have two Select boxes.

first one is `Country` List

Second one is `State` List.

When we are select one Country Related State Will be Displayed.

In our Jsp we can manage to Display List Using Jquery.

But How to Prepare This List in Spring(Java)?

Please Suggest me How to Do this In Java?

Comment: How to Prepare The List of Country and State .. if we give one example  for one country, i will Prepare All the Country List and States.

Comment: @AndrewThompson.. This is for Spring.. When i'm before asking this Question, i'm also see your question..

Comment: You're looking for Spring MVC 3 + Ajax solution (since you say you can manage to display the data using jQuery). After some search on the web, I found [this decent Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7196181/1065197). For your fortune, the case is for country/state. Still, it would be **better** if you search about spring mvc 3 and ajax.

Comment: Exactly same when we create List object for List of Countries, We are using Model Attribute we can get value.. <c:set var="modalAttribute"   value="FORM" />

Answer (score 0):

Create two Bean Interfaces Country and State like :

```
interface Country {

 State state;

}

interface State {

  List<String> states;

}
```

Implement these interfaces with simple getters and setters and then define your initiation configuration in spring.xml file like

```
<bean id ="CountryX" class="CountryImpl">
//Give reference to State bean say StateX in this case.

<bean id ="StateX" class="StateImpl">
// here set the list of states
```

Comment: this process is very hard but i'm thinking Short cut to get all country and state..

Comment: In case you want to do it with Spring, you have to define all the configuration in spring configuration file. And Once you do that, then there is nothing else you have to do .. its done

Comment: i'm comfortable only using annotation.. so i'm not thinking spring configuration files..

Comment: Then you might have to create your own custom annotations like @interface MyAnnotation {  
  String State();  //Code goes here
}

Comment: Actually i'm thinking first Create List of Available Counties then Using This every Object in List We can create Another List for States. If Using Locale Class we can get Countries but Hear how to Prepare States?

Comment: probably the same way you are creating countries. Can you show me the code you have written and tell me the point where you are stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

One more approach would be to use `Map<String,List<String>>` in your **Spring bean xml**

```
 <bean id="beanName" class="package.CountryPojo">
     <property name "countryMap">
        <map>
           <entry key="USA">
              <value>
                 <list merge="true">
                     <value>MN</value>
                     <value>CA</value>
                 </list>
              </value>
           </entry>
           <entry key="UK">
              <value>
                 <list merge="true">
                     <value>XY</value>
                     <value>IJ</value>
                 </list>
              </value>
           </entry>
        </map>      
     </property>
 </bean>
```

Having your bean class like

```
class CountryPojo {

   private Map<String,List<String>> countryMap;

   //getters : setters

}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Replay.. Correct for Using Map Object but we have to maintain nearly 100 of countries in that case XML is heavy.. is their any other way?

Comment: The best way would be to store the info in RDBMS, since you opted spring, I thought above solution can help

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Bean interfaces Country and State like below :

```
 interface Country {

 State state;

}

interface State {

  List<String> states;

}
```

Implement these interfaces with getter and setter and then initialize the configuration in spring.xml file in below way:

```
  <bean id ="CountryTemp" class="CountryImpl">
//Give reference to State bean say StateTemp in this case.

<bean id ="StateTemp" class="StateImpl">
// here set the list of states
```