# How to dynamically populate a select box based on text box input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a text box and a select box as box. The select box values are loaded via ajax call based on the selection in another select box. Now my requirement is as I input value in the text box based on the input my select box should show the values.

```
<form:input id="txtBox"></form:input>

<form:select id="selectBox" path="selectedValue">
  <form:option value="0">Anand</form:option >
  <form:option value="1">Arun</form:option >
  <form:option value="2">Ananya</form:option >
  <form:option value="3">babu</form:option >
</form:select>
```

Now I enter 'a' in the text box the select box should be populated with "Anand","Arun","Ananya".

if I enter 'n' again in the txt box "Anand" and "Ananaya" should be listed.

If I enter any alphabet in the text box that is not in the select box then the select box should be empty.

How to achieve this in Jquery?

Comment: you can use jquery ui autocomplete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Use jquery autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery, JSON, Spring MVC - Dynamically loading select options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196181/jquery-json-spring-mvc-dynamically-loading-select-options)

Comment: You can handle it via ajax calls. Pass the input text to backend on each keyup event and filter the data from backend and get the response. Dynamically update the select options with the backend data.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as others have mentioned you should have a look at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete which provides a excelent option for doing exactly what you described.

If you would prefer not to use a plugin then you can do something like this: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjLgn3kn/)

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type=text]').keyup(function() {

        $('select option:contains("' + $('input[type=text]').val() + '")').show().siblings().hide();

    });

});
```

n.b. this is only a crude proof of concept, it would need refining before you use it in a production situation.